# What is the name of the 'Halo 3 theme song'?

Tags: halo-3, game-music-identification

What is the name of the Halo 3 theme song?  I have found it listed as "[Halo 3 Theme Song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om0M6Ol8FjQ)", but I would like to know the actual name.

I think it is the same song that is played during the last, and best level in Halo 3 when you're driving the wart-hog across the halo. The original video link is dead but here is the same song:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've linked to is actually the [Mjolnir Mix featured in Halo 2](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Halo_Theme_MJOLNIR_Mix). It is a remix of the original Halo theme, from Halo 1.

In Halo 3, there are a few songs you could potentially consider "theme songs". They are [Never Forget](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Never_Forget), [Finish the Fight](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Finish_the_Fight), and arguably [Behold a Pale Horse](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Behold_a_Pale_Horse), which contains samplings from many other songs in the series. A remix of the original theme is also used and it is [One Final Effort](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/One_Final_Effort). A slightly different version of this can be heard in the Warthog section of the last level.

Comment: One final effort is actually played in the [Cortana level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_3_Original_Soundtrack), but since it is basically just a remix of the basic Halo theme, you could say it is played on "Race to the Finish" as well I suppose.

Comment: @Ebongo A quote from the Halo Wiki poge on One Final Effort: "A different version, one that is more true to the original Halo Theme is also featured during the Warthog escape in the last level." That's what my information is based on. Also, if you listen to it, you can just tell lol :)

Answer (score 2):

My OCD got the better of me, and I had to check.  In the level in Halo 3 where you drive the [warthog through hell to safety](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xedx12_halo-3-legendary-guide-halo-race-to_videogames), the song actually playing is "[Halo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003JKMOYS)" (the basic theme).  See [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_Original_Soundtrack) on the soundtrack.  The version in the video above is the "[Halo Theme Mjolnir Mix](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003KRLM1Q)".

As a bonus piece of trivia, it is actually available as a [downloadable track](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNRRLfcUo5I) for Guitar Hero 3.  If you are a fan of the game, it feels pretty sweet to rock out to it on the plastic guitar.

Comment: The version in your video may be the Mjolnir Mix, as was the version released for GH3.  Not sure how specific you are shooting for.

Comment: Yeah, it looks to me like the one in the video is the Mjolnir Mix

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the full track list, that can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_3_Original_Soundtrack#Track_listing).
While there is no one Halo "theme song", "Never Forget" was a key theme in their marketing campaign.